# How to compute an average for each category in a boxplot in Python?

Tags: python, average, boxplot

I am trying to compute the average of earnings in each level of education but it is not working and I don't understand what does the error message mean. Could you help please?

```
mydata['LevelEduc'] = pd.cut(mydata['education'], bins = [0,12,16,float('Inf')],labels=['Low','Medium','High'])

mydata.boxplot(column='education',by='LevelEduc')
matplotlib.pyplot.title("")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()

avg_value = sum('Low') / len('earnings')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/vj/pxgh1vcx2zsf_cs2hld5dxvm0000gn/T/ipykernel_9043/2104741865.py in <module>
      1 #4.Compute the average of earnings for each level of education.
----> 2 avg_value = sum('Low') / len('earnings')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Have you tried searching this error message on Stack Overflow? There are over 1,200 questions and answers with the same error message.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `sum(mydata['Low'])` & `len(mydata['earnings'])` ? Otherwise, it refers to the strings "Low" and "earnings", which are not related to the dataframe columns with those names. And if 'earnings' can contain NA values, then use `mydata['earnings'].count()` instead of `len`. Use `df.head(10).to_clipboard(excel=False)` to copy the first 10 rows of your dataframe to clipboard (as text) which you can then paste into your question. Read this post on [how to provide a **good pandas example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391). Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: You still need to use a `groupby` to get the bins correctly. My comment above is only to address the error you're getting.